# SDL: Certain bitmap not displaying

Tags: c++, sdl

I have come across a very wierd problem. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL.h"

using namespace std;

class MyGame
{
public:

    SDL_Surface* image;
    SDL_Surface* window;
    SDL_Event* e;

    void Start() 
    {
        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

        window = SDL_SetVideoMode(800,600,32,SDL_SWSURFACE);

        image = SDL_LoadBMP("Bitmap.bmp");
        SDL_BlitSurface(image,NULL,window,NULL);
        SDL_FreeSurface(image);

        SDL_Event evt;

        bool programrunning = true;
        while(programrunning)
        {
            SDL_WaitEvent(&evt);
            if(evt.type == SDL_QUIT) programrunning = false;
        }

        SDL_Quit();
    }

    void Update() 
    {
        SDL_Flip(window);
    }
};

int main(int argc,char* args[]) 
{
    MyGame obj;
    obj.Start();
    while(true) 
    {
        obj.Update();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I run this code on Code::Blocks, no errors appear and everything works except for the bitmap. For some reason it doesn't display. However, I once tried replacing Bitmap.bmp with cb.bmp (the Code::Blocks logo that came with the IDE) and it rendered perfectly fine. Also, whenever I close the program Windows gives me this error: "2DGame.exe not responding", no matter what bitmap I use. This is one of the strangest coding problems I have come across ever, please tell me why Bitmap.bmp is being a jerk and how to fix it and also how to fix the error I get whenever I close my program. Thanks!

P.S: You guys asked for the image, here it is:

[image]

Comment: I've edited your question, and removed the part where you ask about the Code::Blocks SDL template, as that's not relevant to *this* particular issue you are having. The template is probably built to just quickly open a window and close immediately. Now, as for your actual question: could you supply the problematic Bitmap.bmp? It's really hard to guess what might be wrong with your particular bitmap.

Comment: The Bitmap is a picture I downloaded off the internet. It is an image that I downloaded off the internet. It's roughly 250x250 in size.

Comment: I didn't ask for the size. I asked for the image. Could you supply it please?

Comment: I supplied the image above

Comment: Thank you. If you yourself download that image from imgur, does it display properly? It's not amazingly useful that you didn't supply the image file, as it goes trough Imgur's converter, and any issues in the BMP file itself disappear, but it seems like the file is fine as imgur can parse it. Also, while trying to load the BMP, does `SDL_GetError()` display anything?

Comment: It looks like you running this using SDL 1.2? SDL_SetVideoMode was removed when moved up to SDL 2. Any reason why you're not using SDL 2?

Comment: I used the link on the lazyfoo tutorial page which led me to SDL 1.2.9.  SDL 2 looks alot easier, I'll give it a go

Comment: You most likely were using the older version of his tutorials. Try this one: http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't supplied the particular bitmap you are having trouble with, I cannot guess what is wrong with the bitmap. Your rendering code seems fine on that part.

When it comes to the program hanging, the cause is quite clear. When an `SDL_QUIT` event is received, you quit your loop that is waiting for that particular event, and call `SDL_Quit();`. However, the while loop inside your `main` still keeps trying to update the window. As of currently, your application can't be exit, because the while loop inside `main` is an infinite loop. All in all, your game loop seems a little ill-formed. You might want to try a simpler approach, where there is only one game loop, and where you use `SDL_PollEvent` for receiving events.

Comment: The Bitmap is a picture I downloaded off the internet. It is an image that I downloaded off the internet. It's roughly 250x250 in size.

Answer (score 1):

[`SDL_LoadBMP`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LoadBMP) can only load bitmap images (i.e. extension `.bmp`). Images from the internet are rarely of this format; they are usually formats like JPEG, PNG or GIF.

For that, you want to look at [**SDL_image**](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/) instead. It's a helper library for SDL that handles loading various image types into SDL. It has a different loading function: [`IMG_Load`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/docs/SDL_image/SDL_image_7.html).

And please, **always check errors in your code.** Your problem could have been caught earlier if you had checked the output of `SDL_LoadBMP`, which would have been null. Like most SDL functions, you can then get a description of the error using [`SDL_GetError`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetError).